# Implementing Neumann boundary conditions for finite volume PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-volume-method

I'm trying to better understand finite volume methods and have started coding up a basic script to solve the diffusion equation $$u_t = u_{xx}$$ which has the finite volume form: $$\frac{\bar{u}^{n+1}_i\ - \bar{u}^n_i }{\Delta t} = \hat{F}_{i+\frac{1}{2}}^n - \hat{F}_{i-\frac{1}{2}}^n$$ where $\bar{u_i}$ is the average value of $u$ over cell $i$ and $\hat{F}$ is the numerical approximation to the flux at a cell interface.

I am using an ENO approximation in order to reproduce the point values $u$ and the derivative values $u_x$ as well. I'm aware of the ENO method to reproduce the numerical flux at each cell, however, I'm confused on how I can implement no flux boundary conditions using this method. Instead, here's what I've tried:

Using my array of known averages, $\bar{u}_i^n$, construct two coefficient matrices. One that approximates the value of the flux, $u_x$, at the left cell interface (which I'll call $L$) and one approximates it at the right cell interface (which I'll call $R$), giving me an equation that looks like $$\bar{u}^{n+1}_i = \bar{u}^n_i - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(R-L)\bar{u}^n_i$$. This allows me to just make the coefficients of the first row of $L$ and the last row of $R$ all zeros in order to implement no flux boundary conditions. However, when doing it this way, I seem to get something that is obviously non-conservative after I advance one time step:

[image: $u$ after a timestep of .01 with initial condition $u(x,0) = erfc(x)$]

This is clearly due to my implementation of the flux conditions, as the interior nodes all give correct values within the prescribed error.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you handle end points where the operators can't reach any data?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused by this question.

Comment: It looks like the large jumps could be first and last sample, and if that is so, it could be because the discrete approximation filters of differentials can't reach any data. You need to find boundary conditions or some regularization to make them nicer.

Comment: How do I apply other boundary conditions other than these? I guess I'm just having a hard time understanding because I thought the point of finite volume methods was that so I can evaluate the flux at cell boundaries and thus there would be no need to discretize the boundary condition for the flux and I could just initialize it. Sorry if I'm being a bit dense, I really just don't know why setting the flux to zero at this boundary should this much of an issue.

Comment: Don't worry about seeming dense. It takes time to learn. Even if you know it well can take time to get to work sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for that, I appreciate it. Could you explain also what you mean by "regularization"? I was looking at this response: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/how-should-boundary-conditions-be-applied-when-using-finite-volume-method. In which the approved answer mentions something about regularizing in the case where the flux doesn't match the prescribed boundary conditions. Could you perhaps explain what he means in the context of that question, if it's not too much?

Comment: Maybe, some useful information is provided in [this](https://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DN2255/ndiff13/Lecture3.pdf) document.